# Trying to plot an object:list date column in a dataset with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've tried `df['release_date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['release_date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')`... but it doesn't match the format of the dates in the file. Example of object list date which is in the file is: 8/14/1960

Can someone help me convert this to a datetime object so that I can plot with matplotlib? or how would I go about plotting a scatter-plot with this data?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Yo alright except you ordered format day month and not month day
Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'release_date':['8/14/1960','8/14/1989'],'value':[20,200]})

import matplotlib .pyplot as plt
#df['release_date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['release_date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
#or
df['release_date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['release_date']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    df.set_index('release_date').plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]